# How to resolve main class not found exception while creating jar?

Tags: java

I am creating an executable jar file of a java project.
I successfully created a sample jar file with Hello world class.
I used following  commands to create a jar:

```
 trail> javac -classpath "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin;" MyClass.java

 bin> jar cvfm MyJar.jar manifest.mf trail\*.class
```

The Contents of my manifest.mf are

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Created-By: 1.5.0_03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
  Main-Class: trial.MyClass
```

This works fine.

Now when I use same procedure to create the jar of my project,
I am getting mainClass not found error.

```
EDIT
My project need 2 third party jar.
So I have compiled  My project by adding this jars in classpath.
I guess the problem is related with this jar file dependencies. 
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
```

Comment: You really need to provide more details of your project.  It looks like you have a directory name "trail" but a package named "trial" in the manifest - is that a typo in the question, or the source of the problem?

Comment: you should not need c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin in your classpath. If you actually have classes in there then I suggest you move them

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Ant and [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) Task for this purpose. Ant makes it very easy for you to configure the attributes of the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you have to set the parameter `Main-Class` to the class witch contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` you wants to call.
Has I can imagine, you want to start with the `MyClass`
Your mainfest should contains:

```
Main-Class: MyClass
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what "your project" consists of. Remember that java cannot load jars from within a jar (atleast while using the -jar flag), so if you have any jar-dependencies you will have to "explode" them into classes/directory style layout.

Comment: Yes there are jar dependencies.How do I "explode" them?

Comment: You can simply unpack them by renaming them to .zip, or use maven or ant-targets that does this for you.